# Cant able to upload file in AWS (used vsftpd) for the user created

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, file-transfer

I have used this (https://blog.e-zest.com/setting-up-sftp-server-on-amazon-ec2) tutorial to create ftp account for another one user in my AWS EC2 instance.

All went well, i have that users public key only so i cant able to login and check myself for file upload.

What they sent is the following error, i didn't get any clue what the error is:

```
2018-12-26 16:45:48 SITE=760603404 CMD=Change dir to /shared/payroll_in/                                                                                                                                           

2018-12-26 16:45:48 SITE=760603404 CMD=Send Documents LOCAL=760603404.OADP.DELA.340001812140000000.0002.O.PDF.gpg REMOTE=760603404.OAD.DELA.340001812140000000.0002.O.PDF.gpg                                     

2018-12-26 16:45:48 SITE=760603404 ERROR sending Documents to data set 760603404.OAD.DELA.340001812140000000.0002.O.PDF.gpg MSG=([Errno 2] No such file or directory: '760603404.OADP.DELA.340001812140000000.0002.O.PDF.gpg')                                                                                                                                                                                                        

2018-12-26 16:45:48 SITE=760603404 CMD=Send Documents LOCAL=760603404.OADP.HECK.390001812192028056.0001.O.PDF.gpg REMOTE=760603404.OAD.HECK.390001812192028056.0001.O.PDF.gpg                                     

2018-12-26 16:45:48 SITE=760603404 ERROR sending Documents to data set 760603404.OAD.HECK.390001812192028056.0001.O.PDF.gpg MSG=([Errno 2] No such file or directory: '760603404.OADP.HECK.390001812192028056.0001.O.PDF.gpg')
```

Extra info:

Folder structure is **/sftp/shared**. these two folders are with the following properties:

permission : 0755
group: sftpusers [1003]
owner : root

there is another two folder inside **shared** folder,

Those two folder with following properties:

permission : 2775
group: sftpusers [1003]
owner : username itself

If do u need more info please ask me, what will be the reason to this error?

Comment: `chmod +x /sftp/shared/payroll_in`

Comment: well the error signifies tha your local files are not available, can you check manually weather this file is available or not 
"760603404.OADP.DELA.340001812140000000.0002"

Comment: @varnit, i cant have the private key to check, so im creating another user to check. i dont have clue how they are connecting, and where they seen this error message. do u have any idea?

Comment: i'm guessing that they are seeing these error messages in their ftp client console

Comment: @varnit any specific name for "ftp client console", so that i can try

Comment: try with filezilla

Comment: @MartinZeitler, given this executable permission but sill same.

Comment: Change the permissions of ‘shared’ directory so that only users of sftpusers group can see and modify the data inside the ‘shared’ directory

`chown root:sftpusers /sftp/shared`